# Vertices automatically change position?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, transforms

Basically every time I work with cylinders or circles i would get this problem.
The points are suppose to be -0.9, but it will automatically change to this number even after every time i manually change vertex to -0.9. Many other points are also like this no matter how much i move it or change it to make it symmetrical. My work requires quite alot of precision so this is quite cumbersome.

WHy does blender do this?

[image]

Comment: You have snapping turned on. Click the little blue and white horseshoe icon in the bar at the top of the window to disable it and see if that help.

Comment: Blender is an animation suite, not a CAD software. Some numerical imprecision are expected. Playing with the units can help you in narrowing the problem down.

Comment: You have your Units Scale set to 0.0001, change it to 0.001 for metric mm. I use Blender to design very accurate parts and I have scale at 0.001 and Length set to Millimeters

Comment: @Psyonic wow that actually worked! Thank you!